# Why qt applications don't use gtk theme?

Tags: qt, gtk, gtk3, gnome, qt6

I have installed some qt6 based applications inside gnome, but the application are using their own borders, font-scale, gui-scale and mouse.

here is the screen shot:

[calibre qt6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NScd3.png)

[texstudio qt6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pcVty.png)

can anyone help me fix this problem?
thank you.

Comment: Please post the code as text, not an image.